# Right alignment of items in Windows.Forms.ListBox

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox

Is there a proper way to align items to the right for ListBoxes from the .net Windows.Forms?

You can use

```
example_box = ListBox()
example_box.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes
```

This enables the right alignment, but also prints your items right to left. Also the formatting does some really strange things here:

'% one two 4.72' gets displayed as 'one two 4.72 %'

For digits only this works quite well, but feels rather wonky. Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RightToLeft layout is meant for the Arabic and Hewbrew cultures, they write text right-to-left.  It also affects how text is rendered, you found a side-effect.  You need to use owner-draw to get it the way you want it.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ReverseListBox : ListBox {
    public ReverseListBox() {
        this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e) {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if (e.Index >= 0 && e.Index < this.Items.Count) {
            var selected = (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected;
            var back = selected ? SystemColors.Highlight : this.BackColor;
            var fore = selected ? SystemColors.HighlightText : this.ForeColor;
            var txt = this.Items[e.Index].ToString();
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, txt, this.Font, e.Bounds, fore, back, TextFormatFlags.Right | TextFormatFlags.SingleLine);
        }
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Works great (at least as IronPython module).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any existing features of Windows Forms that will allow you to do this; you might have to override the control's drawing and draw the thing yourself.