# Change listbox items alignment in windows forms application C#

Tags: c#

I want to change alignment of some listbox items to right, (creating a messaging application) i tried looking at other thread no answer

Comment: Pretty good explanation of how is it done and why

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341650/right-alignment-of-items-in-windows-forms-listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `String.PadRight` as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379340/how-can-i-align-strings-added-as-listbox-items) or a `DataGridView` which is designed to display a sequence of (possibly complex) structures...